# Pulling from Array in Embedded Document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have three documents.

```
User
List
Food
```

A list can have many foods and is embedded inside the user document. I have an action in my controller that when an user is done with a food item, loops through the user's list and removes any association between a list and the particular food the user is completed with.

```
@user.lists.to_a.each do |list|

  list.food_ids.to_a.map do |food_id|
    if food_id.eql? params[:food_id]

      food = Food.find(params[:food_id])

      # Pull food from list
      list.pull(:foods, food)

    end
  end
end

@user.save
```

My models

## User

```
class User

  # INCLUDES
  # ========
  include Mongoid::Document

  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

  # EMBEDDING
  # =========
  embeds_many :lists

  # NESTED ATTRIBUTES
  # =================
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lists
end
```

## List

```
class List
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :foods

  embedded_in :user

  belongs_to: popular_list  
end
```

## Food

```
class Food

  # INCLUDES
  # ========
  include Mongoid::Document

  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

  # ASSOCIATIONS
  # ============
  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :popular_lists

end
```

The problem is, my code does not remove the food item from the list. My question is how can I loop through an array, pull an item from that array, and expect the new array to be saved?

Comment: Could you post your `List` and `Food` definitions? Mongoid does not allow references to embedded models and will raise an exception if I [try to reproduce this](https://gist.github.com/pascalj/e0fd4ea9847aeb1d9776).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because of two problems: First, you cannot embed `List`, because you have references (relations) from/to it.  Make it an own collection with a normal `belongs_to :user`.

You cannot have relations to embedded models, because the other side will only store the id. If you use that relation, Mongoid will call `MyEmbeddedModel.find(related_id)` which cannot find the embedded model, because it's inside another document and not an own collection.

Second, your code is missing the counterparts for `belongs_to :user` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :foods`. The [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_one) states: `Definitions are required on both sides to the relation in order for it to work properly.`  If you add these ([see my gist](https://gist.github.com/pascalj/e0fd4ea9847aeb1d9776)), Mongoid will raise an error that also suggests not to embed `List`:

> (Mongoid::Errors::MixedRelations)
>
> **Problem**:   Referencing a(n) List
> document from the Food document via a relational association is not
> allowed since the List is embedded.
>
> **Summary**:   In order to properly
> access a(n) List from Food the reference would need to go through the
> root document of List. In a simple case this would require Mongoid to
> store an extra foreign key for the root, in more complex cases where
> List is multiple levels deep a key would need to be stored for each
> parent up the hierarchy. Resolution:   Consider not embedding List, or
> do the key storage and access in a custom manner in the application
> code.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. Your answer helped me understand the association issues I have and will help me fix my problem.